# LibreOffice Calcのマクロ記録が出来ない

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice Calc6.3.5.2を使っています。

1列500行ほどのCSVファイルを開いて、データの文字数を整理するために
マクロの記録をクリック
B1にカーソル移動
=MID(A1,1,15)
セルの右下ダブルクリックで最終行までコピー
記録の終了
マクロ保存

以上の手順で、マクロを記録しましたが、マクロの実行を行ってもB2にカーソルが移動するだけです。
何か、手順に誤りがあるでしょうか？
あるいは、LibreOfficeでは上記手順は出来ないのでしょうか？

Excelなら問題なく出来るのですが

Comment: 記録したマクロはテキスト形式で内容を確認できるようであれば、質問文に追記してもらうと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: 古い記事でこんなのがあるようなので、記録したマクロのソースが見られるかも。[LibreOfficeでマクロの記録ができるって知ってた？設定方法を教えます。](http://pineplanter.moo.jp/non-it-salaryman/2016/06/28/libreoffice-macro-record/), [LibreOfficeマクロでBeanShellが使えるとは驚いた](http://pineplanter.moo.jp/non-it-salaryman/2016/05/25/libreoffice-beanshell-1st/)